# td css works in chrome but not in IE

Tags: html, css

I want to publish some in table where the table td widths, BG colours are different. I designed the following css  which is working fine in Chrome and Fire fox but not giving required out-put in Internet explorer. Can any body help me in this regard.

HTML:

```
<td class="td_1">Games</td>
<td class="td_2">Sports</td>
```

CSS:

```
.td_1 {    
  width:200px; 
  height:50px;
  max-width:200px;
  min-width:200px; 
  max-height:50px; 
  min-height:50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  color: red;
}
.td_2 {    
  width:300px; 
  height:50px;
  max-width:300px;
  min-width:300px; 
  max-height:50px; 
  min-height:50px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: OK but what's the required output? What doesn't work in IE?

Comment: Yes it is not working in IE (the TD widths and Bg colours are not working in case of IE

Comment: which IE version you are using?

Comment: could you elaborate on how is it 'not giving required out-put in Internet explorer' ? wrong width? wrong color?

Comment: it IE6+ version (both width and colour)

Comment: I've checked in IE6, IE7 and IE8. all styles applied. make sure some other CSS styles are overlapping over this style.

Answer (score 0):

there is no way in the world you would get wrong color. please see that your Internet Explorer's user-agent styles dont override your stylesheet. try using a reset.css sheet to reset all IE's default values.

include the reset.css first before all other stylesheets. you can get a free one [Here](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)